# Let Multiple clients use unique Accounts in a redis database

Tags: redis

So I have multiple redis clients like:
c1,c2,c3,...

And in my database there are multiple unique accounts like:
a1,a2,a3,...

I want to offer each client to 'block' an account if the account is in use by a client the other client shouldnt be allowed to use it. Also If a client crashes which holds an account the blocked accounts should be unblocked.

What I currently do is(for example the account with the id 0):

```
K := account:0:used

watch(K)
multi

if exists(K)
abort

exec:
setWithTimeout(K,5*60*1000,"1")//Ensure Its blocked for 5 Minutes
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I may wanted to use scripts but I think there should be an easier option to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SET](http://redis.io/commands/set) supports the following invocation (I'm not sure what language/client you're using though):

```
SET account:0:used EX 3600 NX
```

This way you do the entire thing in a single command w/o WATCH/MULTI/EXEC

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer Its perfect :). I'm using go with the go-redis. It doesnt seem to offer this but the command builder allows me to easily add new commands.